# Process and threads in Linux

Tags: c, process, pthreads

> "Copying memory for a new process adds an additional performance
>   overhead relative to creating a new thread."

How to check this on Linux?

Comment: Do both. And time it!

Comment: As Joe said: time it, or just _think_: why would spawining a thread with _shared_ memory be faster than starting a new process and copying X bytes into newly allocated memory be slower?

Comment: Except that on Linux (and most other modern operating systems) the copying will not be done until you write to a memory page. So the only copying made initially is the memory *map*, not the actual memory. Still some overhead, but not by very much.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: well obviously, but if you have to spawn a new thread/process, chances are you're not attempting to do something trivial...

Comment: Beside testing it by timing you could also take a minute and think about how copying memory is a performance overhead over not copying.

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem What I'm getting at is that it's not going to be trivial to just measure the time used by `fork` compared to e.g. `pthread_create`, as the difference for those calls will be negligible. You actually have to do something non-trivial activity in the child process/thread for it to be measurable.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg - maybe copy-on-write of the parent address space would be enough? Though you're right that it'll be hard to measure.  And it's not quite the same overhead measurement.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Ah, OK... now I see. Well, I'm with you on that, of course. To me, this question sort of _implies_ a non-trivial task being forked/spawned